# Reducing variable voltage to a lower variable voltage in a dc circuit

Tags: voltage, resistors

I have a Lithium Ion battery pack which has an output voltage ranging from 42v to 58 volts.

I'd like to connect a voltage display to this so that I can view the batterys relative state of charge.

The voltage displays I've seen on ebay and such (which can be used to measure up to 100v) require a voltage of between 5v and 30v to power them.

Is it possible to connect a resistor in series with the voltage display to reduce the voltage from the battery to the voltage required by the display?

Thanks,

John

Comment: how much current does the voltmeter display need?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a regulator to power the Voltage Current meter.
There are many options and two of them which could strike my mind is using:

1. **Buck regulator** such as LM2574
2. **Linear regulator** with extended input range using FET and may be two in series in order to keep the dissipation low.

**Option 1** is *simple*.

Set the output voltage to 20 V nominal and the display should be fine. Normally the power consumption of the volt-ammeter will be ~<30 mA. So, load is not a concern. Then, you can hook up the input probes of the meter to the battery.

[image]

**Option 2**
This is not complete solution but the hint to the design:
Instead of TPS79228 you can use 7805 regulator too, but care to be taken while choosing FET. Breakdown voltage has to be higher than 60 V . Power dissipation and gate voltage to have the load current of at least 40 mA are two second major concerns to be considered .

Reference: [TI application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva119/slva119.pdf)
[image]